# Bitbake doesn't fetch git repo and throws no error

Tags: yocto, bitbake, yocto-recipe

I am trying to add the files of a git repository inside my console-image. In this matter, I created a recipe inside a layer named `meta-rpi` (a layer built by the guy that wrote [this](https://jumpnowtek.com/rpi/Raspberry-Pi-4-64bit-Systems-with-Yocto.html) article, whose yocto image I reproduce). So inside `meta-rpi` I created a recipe called `recipes-web-server`, within it another folder named `backend`, and finally, inside it, I put my recipe `backend_git.bb`.

The `backend_git.bb` file has the following content in it:

```
DESCRIPTION = "Backend repo"
SECTION = ""
DEPENDS = ""
LICENSE = "MIT"

// here I made sure to copy a commit SHA code from the main branch
#SRCREV = "somecode"

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/myUsername/myRepo.git;branch=main;protocol=http"

inherit npm-install-global
```

And then in `conf/layer.conf` of `meta-rpi` I have this non-modified conf:

```
# We have a conf and classes directory, append to BBPATH
BBPATH .= ":${LAYERDIR}"

# We have a recipes directory, add to BBFILES
BBFILES += "${LAYERDIR}/recipes*/*/*.bb ${LAYERDIR}/recipes*/*/*.bbappend ${LAYERDIR}/images/*.bb"

BBFILE_COLLECTIONS += "meta-rpi64"
BBFILE_PATTERN_meta-rpi64 := "^${LAYERDIR}/"
BBFILE_PRIORITY_meta-rpi64 = "16"

LAYERSERIES_COMPAT_meta-rpi64 = "dunfell"
```

So everything seems alright. The build runs fine and I was able to flash the image to an SD Card and test it on my raspberry.

After the OS was ready to use, I got inside `cd /` and then ran `find . -name *backend*` and other `find . -name`  of various folders inside my git repository but couldn't find it.

So my question is, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you add the library to the mandatory things to be installed (or is it pulled by any third party software)?

Comment: @OznOg sorry, but I am not sure what you refer to

Comment: by default, bb does build only libs/binaries that are marked to be installed and their dependencies. So if you do not use it in a binairy somewhere or do not force the install, it just won't be compiled/installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your recipe is not added to the image.

Add this line to your custom image or `local.conf`:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " backend"
```

This will force the recipe to be built and shipped.

Comment: Yes, that was it, thanks! Sorry for the stupid question but is very hard to find resources regarding yocto